# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure deepanshu_temp, Line 141 Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using the following code

```
(select
     CASE
        WHEN [Primary Plan] > 0 
           THEN
              CASE
                 WHEN [market_type] = 'WH'
                    THEN
                       CASE 
                          when @a > 20
                             then 1
                          WHEN (((#temp.[MTD Primary] + #temp.[stockC&F])/(#temp.[Primary Plan])) < ((@a/30) + 20) )

                    THEN 
                    (((#temp.[Primary Plan]) *((@a/30) + 20)) -  (#temp.[stockC&F] + #temp.[MTD Primary]))
  --                  when (((#temp.[MTD Primary] + #temp.[stockC&F] +#temp.stockplant + #temp.stocktransact)/#temp.[Primary Plan]) < ((@a/30) + 20) )
                    else 0
                END
            ELSE ''
                end
    ELSE '-'
            END AS 'availibility_alert')
```

I am inserting this  value based on some calculation in temp table (`#temp2`) but getting an error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure deepanshu_temp, Line 141
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
>
> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure deepanshu_temp, Line 141
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I have analysed that the error is in the line after 'then' in my code:

```
(((#temp.[Primary Plan]) *((@a/30) + 20)) -  (#temp.[stockC&F] + #temp.[MTD Primary]))
```

I have also checked that the columns I am using are of type `decimal(38,6)`
but still not able to find out.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is the type of @a ?

Comment: Replace columns & variables with a number literal one by one. You'll find the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code indented a bit better:

```
select (CASE WHEN [Primary Plan] > 0 
             THEN (CASE WHEN [market_type] = 'WH'
                        THEN (CASE when @a > 20
                                   then 1
                                   WHEN (((#temp.[MTD Primary] + #temp.[stockC&F])/(#temp.[Primary Plan])) < ((@a/30) + 20) )

                                   THEN (((#temp.[Primary Plan]) *((@a/30) + 20)) -  (#temp.[stockC&F] + #temp.[MTD Primary]))
                                   else 0
                              END)
                        ELSE ''
                   end)
        ELSE '-'
    END) AS availability_alert
```

Notice that you are returning some values as numbers (`0`) and some as strings (`-`).

SQL Server has to define the return type.  It decides on a number.  The problem is probably converting `-` to a number.